# Responsive Wordpress Navigation Bar - Additional CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

Hi I'm stuck to customize this additional CSS in Wordpress.I use a theme called Poza Child and it's maximum width (100%) as the picture below. I wanted to make a responsive navigation bar that fill the screen.

[image: As you can see here, there's a gap (black and grey). I wanted to make a responsive navigation bar (all black).]

As you can see here, there's a gap (black and grey). I wanted to make a responsive navigation bar (all black) just like the one below.

[image]

However because of the theme used, I have to add additional CSS to make it full-width and responsive to any screen size. This is my code snippet of the wordpress additional CSS.

```
#primary #content {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#header .nav-main {
    background-color: #000000;
}

#header .nav-main .container {
    width: 100%;
}

.heading {
 border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

I've tried to change it to negative value, in pixels (eg. -380px) but it's not responsive for tablets and mobile. How can I overcome this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the web address located? You need to adjust the correct tag on HTML

Comment: @JaysonJohn What do you mean by tag on html?

Comment: You're suppose to adjust ie .wrapper and not the ie .container

Comment: Can you also include the relevant html for the navbar? For example, is it in a container that is limiting its max width?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone. I have found my solution. As you guys stated, it's the container that had been the problem.

It should be like this:

```
 #header .container {
    width: 100%;}
```

I just deleted the nav-main. Thanks all!